# Flutterflow | Limitations of the test/run feature

Tags: flutterflow

I am developing an app with Flutterflow that requires a package called flutter_inappwebview.

Such package only supports Android/iOS platforms.

When I am trying to test/run my app through FF, nothing happens. I can't figure out if this is a normal behavior (e.g. FF cannot emulate Android/iOS environment through its web interface) or if this is me screwing up with the code.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [package](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_inappwebview) is not compatible with Web as seen here [image]

FlutterFlow runs on a Web browser so this is only testable on IOS or Android build type

Comment: Thanks Daniel. So to be sure I understand, I could still use it within Flutterflow to develop my app but I would only be able to test it by downloading the code on my machine (with Flutter installed and VS Code for example) and emulating an Android phone.

Comment: Correct :) that will work